# Casting to (char) in Stream.map() Does Not Produce Desired Result

Tags: java, java-stream

java.util.stream is challenging my notion of chars.  I am attempting to perform a simple character rotation of a string, where I simply add 1 to the int value of each character.  I start with "abcd".chars() (a stream), and then I map.  But I don't seem to be able to cast the ints -> char during the map.  Why am I not getting the desired result?

This is vanilla JDK17 (temurin).

```
    jshell> "abdc".chars().map(c -> c + 1).collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::append, StringBuilder::append)
$43 ==> 9899101100
```

Wait; thats not what I want.  These are the int values! Let's try a cast to char:

```
jshell> "abdc".chars().map(c -> (char)c + 1).collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::append, StringBuilder::append)
$44 ==> 9899101100
```

Ok, that had zero effect.  Let's use an explicit map step:

```
jshell> "abdc".chars().map(c -> c + 1).map(c1 -> (char)c1).collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::append, StringBuilder::append)
$45 ==> 9899101100
```

Huh? wtf?  Ok, let's force the cast during the reduce step:

```
jshell> "abcd".chars().map(c -> c + 1).collect(()->new StringBuilder(), (c,d)->c.append((char)d), (c1, c2)->c1.append(c2))
$46 ==> bcde
```

Finally!  But WHY?  Why doesn't the map to char flow across the stream?  What am I missing?  I know this is a newbie question, but I would appreciate being educated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As to *why* you have the problem, see the [Answer by Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75802678/642706).

You can avoid the entire problem easily by using [code point](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integers rather than the broken legacy type `char`.

Furthermore, your code fails with most characters.  Again, solved by using code points.

## Code point, not `char`

The `char` type has been essentially broken since Java 2, and legacy since Java 5. As a 16-bit value, the `char` is physically incapable of representing most of the over 149,000 characters defined in [Unicode](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode).

While `char` is limited to a range of 0 to just over 65,000, code points range from zero to just over a million. Most of that range is not yet assigned, and some is set aside permanently for private use.

Let’s modify your code:

- Replace your `.chars` call with [`.codePoints`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#codePoints()).
- Call [`appendCodePoint`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#appendCodePoint(int)) instead of that first `append`.

Voilà, no more casting confusion.

```java
String s =
    "abdc"
    .codePoints()  // Returns an `IntStream` object. 
    .map( codePoint -> codePoint + 1 )
    .collect( 
        StringBuilder::new , 
        StringBuilder::appendCodePoint , 
        StringBuilder::append 
    )              // Returns a `StringBuilder` object. 
    .toString() ;
```

See this code run [at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/LL7P6E).

> bced

Comment: Calling `char` “broken” is too harsh. It’s important to understand the limitations, i.e. that a `char` represents a UTF-16 unit, just like it is important to understand that even a Unicode codepoint is not always sufficient to represent a single character…

Comment: I upvoted Jon, but I also upvoted your answer.  You are actually raising another issue altogether re using char vs codepoint.  Of course you are right about this.  Fortunately, this is not code I would try to sneak past a code review :-)

Comment: @Holger Sorry, but `"ac".length()` returning `4` is broken. I am mystified why people get so defensive around this fact. An accident of history: Java happened to adopt Unicode just before the consortium realized that assuming a total of 65,000 characters in the world was a poor choice. And the Java team made the mistake of exposing the implementation details of `String` as the `char` type. All that is water under the bridge. The Java team did what they could to ameliorate the situation of `char`. But to pretend that `char` is not a failure is unhelpful, especially to newbies.

Comment: And `"O̊".codePoints().count()` still returns `2`. If you prefer emoji examples, try `"‍".codePoints().count()`. It’s not helpful to call `char` broken and pretend that using codepoints would solve all problems regarding the difference between code units and characters.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, I wouldn't expect `(char) c + 1` to work anyway, as that doesn't cast the *result* to `char`. It only casts `c` to `char`. You really wanted `.map(c -> (char) (c + 1))`.

However, that *still* results in an `IntStream`, because there's no such type as "a stream of characters". [`String.chars()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#chars()) returns an [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html), and your call to `IntStream.map` resolves to `IntStream map​(IntUnaryOperator mapper)`.

Basically what you *want* is a `CharStream` type (like `IntStream` but for `char`) - but that doesn't exist.

Comment: Ah!  The IntStream!!  Why didn't I look at that api doc?  You are so right!  Thank you!!  I am also reading Basil's answer as well and he also has an excellent explanation.  Can I upvote 2 answers?

Answer (score 0):

The `+` operator will always produce an int (or float or double, if any operand is float or double).  This is because both operands are promoted to int values (or long values, if either operand is already a long).

So, your first attempt, `c -> (char)c + 1`, is really doing this:

```
c -> (int) ((char) c) + 1
```

because that’s how numeric promotion works.

Your second attempt’s outcome is due to the fact that [String.chars() returns an IntStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#chars()).  When you do `map(c1 -> (char)c1)` you are actually calling the [map method of IntStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#map(java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator)), whose argument is an IntUnaryOperator.  Thus, the lambda's returned value (`(char)c1`) is promoted to int.

Using [mapToObj](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#mapToObj(java.util.function.IntFunction)) would probably work, though you’d be creating java.lang.Character instances which would have less than ideal efficiency.

Your final attempt works because you are explicitly appending a char value, so it doesn’t matter whether it was an int in the stream.

Basil is right: working with code points is better than char values, both because it removes ambiguity and because the char type is not able to represent all valid Unicode characters.